# Finding Next ID

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I need to Find the next CustomerID . This code works great if there is already one record is available in database but if there is no record in the database i.e It is to insert First Record The error Occurs......

**Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.**

I have the following code

```
public int NextSID()
    {
        String query = "Select max(SupplierID) as MaxSID FROM Suppliers";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, Connectivity.cn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                SupID = 1;
                return SupID;
            }
            else
            {
                SupID = Convert.ToInt16(dt.Rows[0]["MaxSID"])+1;
                return SupID;
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return -1;
        }
```

Is any body here to solve my problem

Comment: Don't try to *find* and set the new ID - let SQL Server handle this, by using an `INT IDENTITY` column. SQL Server will automatically assign a new ID for each row being inserted.

Comment: what could possibly go wrong....! ;)  As marc_s says, use an IDENTITY. The above code is flawed.

Comment: ID is a pure _Technical Key_ and should be never ever used in code (other than for searching and comparing objects), since it has no meaning outside the database. Looks like you're confusing the concepts of _Technical_ vs. _Natural Key_ here.

Comment: Dont do it. But if you have a reason, `Select isnull(max(SupplierID),0)` will help.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to set the column of your table as [INT IDENTITY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) and then SQL Server will take care of the automatic assignment of the ID's

Also to note that you cant add the IDENTITY column to the existing column of your table so you need to create a new identity column and copy the data over using an identity insert command of you want to keep the old values

You may check out this article for adding a IDENTITY column to an existing table

- **[Add or drop identity property for an existing SQL Server column](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1397/add-or-drop-identity-property-for-an-existing-sql-server-column/)**

Answer (score 0):

**While i agreed with @Rahul Tripathi,**
You may also change the SQL Query Statements to like this

```
"Select IsNull(max(SupplierID), 0) + 1 as MaxSID FROM Suppliers"
```

and no need to check if the returned value is DBNull or icrement the id in your code.